# Modify photos of the album photo

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to develop an application that modify photos of the album photo, (exactly adding tags to the photos). 
It is possible to modify the content of the album photo from the application? (replace the photo with the tagged one)?
If it's possible, it is best to copy the picture in the sandbox, edit it, and send it back to the album photo or modify directly the photo without copying it in the application sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't not change a photo in the photo album.
You can copy them, them edit them and add a new photo to the photo album.

You can use [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to allow the user to select an image from the photo library. Or use [AssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=AssetsLibrary) to roll your own image picker.

You will have to use [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) to save the an `UIImage` to the photo library.